# How to find the difference between two rows of data consisting of date and time in R

Tags: r

I am working with a data file consisting of one column of date and time as

```
df
    time_stamp
1 2003-09-06T20:21:51Z  (2003-09-06--> year-month-days-hours-mintutes-seconds)
2 2003-09-06T20:22:36Z
3 2003-09-06T20:22:51Z
4 2003-09-06T20:23:06Z
5 2003-09-06T20:24:56Z
6 2003-09-06T20:25:06Z
```

I want to find the difference between the two rows based on unit of minutes.  I have applied this code to 1st convert the data into a date format, but it gives me an error like:

```
 x<-as.Date(df,format='%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')
 Error in as.Date.default(datew, format = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S") : 
  do not know how to convert 'datew' to class “Date”
```

while the mode(df) shows a results of "list"

Any help will highly be appreciated.  My output should look like this as:

```
 df
    time_stamp                   time_duration
1 2003-09-06T20:21:51Z              0
2 2003-09-06T20:22:36Z              1
3 2003-09-06T20:22:51Z              0.25  
4 2003-09-06T20:23:06Z              0.25
5 2003-09-06T20:24:56Z              1.8
6 2003-09-06T20:25:06Z              0.17
```

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: How about removing the `T,Z` and then use `difftime`. i.e. `v1 <- as.POSIXct(gsub('[TZ]', '', df1$time_stamp), format='%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S'); difftime(v1[-1], v1[-length(v1)], unit='mins')`

Comment: applying your suggested code give me the results as "Time difference of  mins"

Comment: Your description  is`I want to find the difference between the two rows based on unit of minutes`.  So, I am not sure what you need.  You can coerce it to a vector with `as.vector(difftime(v1[-1], ...`

Comment: if we look at the proposed output then you will understand my problem and proposed answer ,

Comment: I am giving some ideas and I followed your description.

Comment: I appreciate your rsponse but I am not good in r programming so I just share the resut of the code you suggested to me

Comment: Here is what i got `c(0, difftime(v1[-1], v1[-length(v1)], unit='mins'))#[1] 0.0000000 0.7500000 0.2500000 0.2500000 1.8333333 0.1666667`  Except for the 2nd entry, it is almost the same as your output.  I don't know whether you `round` the output or not

Comment: here is way I am using it                                                                                            v1 <- as.POSIXct(gsub('[TZ]', '', df$time_stamp), format='%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S')
> difftime(v1[-1], v1[-length(v1)], unit='mins')
Time difference of  mins

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your comment.  I showed the results I got.

Comment: ohh thank you very much its work now I was using the wrong dataframe thanks alot

Comment: Yeah, @akrun 's difftime was the way to go. Look at `help(difftime)` if you want to see how it works, since it can use units other than the `mins` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be passing a list to the `as.Date` function, and it doesn't know how to deal with lists. Try the following.

First I create your data

```
time_stamp <- 
c(
 "2003-09-06T20:21:51Z",             
 "2003-09-06T20:22:36Z",             
 "2003-09-06T20:22:51Z",             
 "2003-09-06T20:23:06Z",             
 "2003-09-06T20:24:56Z",             
 "2003-09-06T20:25:06Z")

df <- list(time_stamp=time_stamp)
```

Now we turn it into a POSIX date. Note that my `format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"` argument differs from yours, since yours produced an error when I tried it. The `format` has to reflect the nature of your date string. See `help(strptime)` for details.

```r
x<-as.POSIXct(df$time_stamp,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" , tz="GMT")

# Do the comparison as @akrun suggested
time_duration <- difftime(x[-1], x[-length(x)], unit='mins')
# Add a zero to the start 
time_duration <- c(0 , time_duration)

# Make your dataframe
df <- data.frame( time_stamp=df$time_stamp , time_duration=time_duration )
```

And the result is what you wanted:

```
> df
            time_stamp time_duration
1 2003-09-06T20:21:51Z     0.0000000
2 2003-09-06T20:22:36Z     0.7500000
3 2003-09-06T20:22:51Z     0.2500000
4 2003-09-06T20:23:06Z     0.2500000
5 2003-09-06T20:24:56Z     1.8333333
6 2003-09-06T20:25:06Z     0.1666667
```